# drag svg element onto HTML element

Tags: jquery-ui, svg, d3.js, drag-and-drop

I would like to drag a svg element onto HTML element.
Not sure what a smart way to do so.

However, I think my method is dirty, but I think I can start drag from svg element with d3.behavior.drag() and on drag function of d3, I am going to clone a copy(please think it is simply a circle object) and let jquery ui handle the drag events. 
The problem is I don't know how to trigger drag event on newly created jquery element.

```
var drag= d3.behavior.drag()
   .on("drag", function(d) {
       // make a Clone html object .dragging-node

       $('.dragging-node').attr('draggable', true);
       $('.dragging-node').trigger('dragstart');

   });
var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
            .data(nodes)
          .enter().append("svg:g")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .call(drag);
```

Any idea how to start drag for this newly created clone object? 
Or is there any smarter way to get what I want?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I dont understand; why are you copying the original element?

Comment: Well, this is my understanding that svg element cannot go outside of svg container. Cannot be dragged out of svg. That is the first and most important reason. There are some other reasons, but they are not worth to list here. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: ok, how to revese? create an HTML object and drag this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did something like this once, and it worked ok for simple stuff, but after some time it became clear that using jQueryUI's Draggable is saner, since it's much more robust. I also needed to use Droppable functionality in conjunction; maybe your needs are less demanding. If so:

You don't need to artificially trigger events from the cloned element (aka "drag helper" in jQueryUI's draggable terminology). Instead, let the events continue to be triggered on the element that initiated the drag and has the drag behavior applied to it, but update the helper's position.

Something like this:

```
// Helper is the cloned element, which doesn't exist until dragging begins
// (alternatively it could pre-exist but be hidden)
var $helper = null

// the parent container of $helper, 
// which presumably is outside of the SVG
var $helperParent = $('body')

var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
  .on("dragstart", function(d) {
    $helper = ... // somehow make the cloned helper, on dragstart (not on drag)
      .appendTo($helperParent)
  })
  .on("drag", function(d) {
    // determine the mouse position relative to the helper's parent
    // (not relative to the SVG element that initiated the drag)
    mousepos = d3.mouse($helperParent[0])

    // update the helper's position
    $helper.css({
      left: mousepos[0],
      top: mousepos[1]
    });
  })
  .on("dragend", function(d) {
    // remove (or hide) the helper
    $helper.remove();
  });
```

Comment: I have thought that manually triggering the mouse event was necessary, but this code snippet works OK. Even though I have accomplished what I want before this answer, I followed the way in the answer as it makes more sense. Thx!

Comment: You said that "using jQueryUI's Draggable is saner", but jQueryUI's Draggable can't handle svg drag&drop, let alone SVG to HTML drag&drop.

What is the solution you have found to be the best one regarding to SVG to HTML drag&drop and SVG to SVG drag&drop?

Comment: @EyalOfri Now that you mention it, I realize I've only used it with HTML not SVG. Didn't know about the SVG limitation. If you make an SVG `<rect>` into a draggable or a droppable, what happens? You don't get any events during drag? I haven't tried looking, but jQueryUI is so old by now that I wonder if there are new libraries nowadays that can do better — especially if older browser support is not important.